# getting the result of ps -ef as a variable

Tags: bash

I trying to build a script in linux - bash, being new to it. I would like to assign the output of the command `ps -ef` as a variable.  Can someone help me with that? The trivial `myVariable = ps -ef` is unfortunately not working.

Comment: OK, I got some answers.
Either `myVariable=`ps -ef``
Either `myVariable=$(ps -ef)`

thanks a lot guys for that really quick answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
myVariable=`ps -ef`
```

or:

```
 myVariable=$(ps -ef)
```

Note no spaces around the '=' sign.

Answer (score 4):

```
myVariable=$(ps -ef)
# or
myVariable=`ps -ef`
```

Comment: And the syntax is highlighted (at least in emacs) in the first case, and isn't in second.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 myVariable=`ps -ef`   # back tic, upper left on most keyboards
```

Then the real fun of parsing the results can begin

Comment: it's not working: 
`[root@stpvsrv0018 RServer]# myVariable ='ps -ef'
-bash: myVariable: command not found`

Comment: my bad, lose the spaces around the '='

Comment: You are brave to try your hand at scripting from root :) at least try to use a low level account until your script works as expected. One bad goof and you wiped out a root drive.

Answer (score 0):

myVariable=`ps -ef` or myVariable=$(ps -ef)